# XPath group sorted children based on child value

Tags: xpath

I have a following xml

```
<doc>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>123456789</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>111111111</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>1</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>She Sells Sea Shells by the Sea Shore and she also</ActivityNarrativeText>
  </ActivityNarrativeInformation>
 <ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>123456789</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>111111111</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>3</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>triple shot frappuccino, extra hot, with whipped cream in a tall cup </ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>123456789</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>111111111</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>2</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>likes to take long walks on the beach while she drinks a</ActivityNarrativeText>
  </ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>987654321</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>222222222</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>486</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>It was a dark and stormy night; the rain fell in torrents--except at occasional intervals, when
 </ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>987654321</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>222222222</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>488</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>scene lies), rattling along the housetops, and fiercely agitating the scanty flame of the lamps that
</ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>987654321</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>222222222</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>487</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>was checked by a violent gust of wind which swept up the streets (for it is in London that our
</ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>987654321</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>222222222</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>489</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>struggled against the darkness.
</ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>55555555</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>77777777</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>31921</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>Papa Bear was very big and growly. Mamma Bear was middle-sized and pleasant.
</ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>55555555</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>77777777</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>31923</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>Papa bear loved to fix things around the house; Mama bear loved to grow flowers in her garden; and, Baby bear loved playing in the yard. They were very happy. </ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>55555555</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>77777777</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>31920</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>Once upon a time there were three bears, Papa Bear, Mamma Bear and Baby Bear
</ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>55555555</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>77777777</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>31922</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>And Baby Bear, well, he was small, and
sometimes he squeaked! They lived in a pretty little house on the edge of the forest
</ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
</doc
```

I need to group those entries by `ActivityID` and concatenate `ActivityNarrativeText` in such a way, that it is sorted by `ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber`

Edit: based on the comment

So the end results looks like this for the first element

```
She Sells Sea Shells by the Sea Shore and she also likes to take long walks on the beach while she drinks a triple shot frappuccino, extra hot, with whipped cream in a tall cup
```

Is this doable using XPath?
I tried to go with the sort function (xpath 3.1) and then join, but the results are not there yet

`string-join(sort(//ActivityNarrativeText[../ActivityID=123456789], ../ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber))`

Result:
`likes to take long walks on the beach while she drinks aShe Sells Sea Shells by the Sea Shore and she alsotriple shot frappuccino, extra hot, with whipped cream in a tall cup`

Comment: *"Is this doable using XPath?"* - No. XPath is for selecting nodes that exist in the document, not for creating new documents with different nodes. You need XQuery or XSLT for constructing new documents.

Comment: So, if we go just for selecting activity according to rules I mentioned i.e. concatenate in specific order those with the same activity id? How should I tackle that?

Comment: Concatenating things *is* making new nodes. Look at the nodes in your source document. Those are the nodes you can select with XPath. Any nodes that don't look exactly like those you already have, you can't select with XPath. That's what "XPath is a selection language" means.

Comment: I thought I have reached another problem, so described it in new quesiton: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68237213/xpath-sorting-not-persistent 
But based on your comment @Tomalak I might not be able to achieve what I want?

Comment: ...you can select the result of `concat()`, but that's gonna be a single flat string. You want a structured document as the result, and that's not something XPath was designed to do.

Comment: Oh no, I need a flat string not a structured output. Maybe my question was not correctly phrased.