# XPath sorting not persistent?

Tags: xpath, xpath-3.1

I have a following XML:

```
<doc>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>123456789</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>111111111</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>1</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>She Sells Sea Shells by the Sea Shore and she also</ActivityNarrativeText>
  </ActivityNarrativeInformation>
 <ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>123456789</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>111111111</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>3</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>triple shot frappuccino, extra hot, with whipped cream in a tall cup </ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>123456789</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>111111111</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>2</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>likes to take long walks on the beach while she drinks a</ActivityNarrativeText>
  </ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>987654321</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>222222222</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>486</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>It was a dark and stormy night; the rain fell in torrents--except at occasional intervals, when
 </ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>987654321</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>222222222</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>488</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>scene lies), rattling along the housetops, and fiercely agitating the scanty flame of the lamps that
</ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>987654321</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>222222222</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>487</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>was checked by a violent gust of wind which swept up the streets (for it is in London that our
</ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>987654321</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>222222222</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>489</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>struggled against the darkness.
</ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>55555555</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>77777777</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>31921</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>Papa Bear was very big and growly. Mamma Bear was middle-sized and pleasant.
</ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>55555555</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>77777777</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>31923</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>Papa bear loved to fix things around the house; Mama bear loved to grow flowers in her garden; and, Baby bear loved playing in the yard. They were very happy. </ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>55555555</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>77777777</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>31920</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>Once upon a time there were three bears, Papa Bear, Mamma Bear and Baby Bear
</ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>55555555</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>77777777</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>31922</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>And Baby Bear, well, he was small, and
sometimes he squeaked! They lived in a pretty little house on the edge of the forest
</ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
</doc
```

I need to group ActivityNarrativeInformation elements by `ActivityID` and concatenate `ActivityNarrativeText` in such a way, that it is sorted by `ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber`

I managed to sort elements with following XPath query (XPath 3.1)
`sort(//ActivityNarrativeInformation[ActivityID=123456789], (), function($ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber) {$ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber})`

So the result looks like this:

```
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>123456789</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>111111111</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>1</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>She Sells Sea Shells by the Sea Shore and she also</ActivityNarrativeText>
  </ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>123456789</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>111111111</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>2</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>likes to take long walks on the beach while she drinks a</ActivityNarrativeText>
  </ActivityNarrativeInformation>
<ActivityNarrativeInformation>
  <ActivityID>123456789</ActivityID>
  <ActivityNarrativeInformationID>111111111</ActivityNarrativeInformationID>
  <ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>3</ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>
  <ActivityNarrativeText>triple shot frappuccino, extra hot, with whipped cream in a tall cup </ActivityNarrativeText>
</ActivityNarrativeInformation>
```

The probelm however is, that if I want to limit down above to just all `ActivityNarrativeText` by adding `/ActivityNarrativeText` at the end like this

`sort(//ActivityNarrativeInformation[ActivityID=123456789], (), function($ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber) {$ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber})/ActivityNarrativeText`

or

`sort(//ActivityNarrativeInformation[ActivityID=123456789]/ActivityNarrativeText, (), function($seq) {$seq/ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber})`

The order is lost:

```
<ActivityNarrativeText>She Sells Sea Shells by the Sea Shore and she also</ActivityNarrativeText>
<ActivityNarrativeText>triple shot frappuccino, extra hot, with whipped cream in a tall cup </ActivityNarrativeText>
<ActivityNarrativeText>likes to take long walks on the beach while she drinks a</ActivityNarrativeText>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the right answer not to use `/` after sorting but `!` instead, one of your attempts would actually work if your sort function argument selected the right element as the sort key:

```
sort(//ActivityNarrativeInformation[ActivityID=123456789]/ActivityNarrativeText, (), function($text) {$text/../ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber})
```

Answer (score 2):

You lose the order when you write `/ActivityNarrativeText`, and it returns the `<ActivityNarrativeText>` in the same order they have in the input file

`/something` with nodes does not just mean map it to the child.

It means

- Map it
- Reorder all nodes to the input document order
- Remove duplicates

You could use `!ActivityNarrativeText`

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is extract a coherenet sentece from your sample xml from that particular `ActivityID`, this expression

```
string-join(sort(//ActivityNarrativeInformation[ActivityID=123456789]/ActivityNarrativeText/concat(normalize-space()," "), (), function($ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber) {$ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber}))
```

should output

```
She Sells Sea Shells by the Sea Shore and she also likes to take long walks on the beach while she drinks a triple shot frappuccino, extra hot, with whipped cream in a tall cup
```

Comment: Testing it here: https://www.videlibri.de/cgi-bin/xidelcgi, but still the results are as described, i.e. the order is incorrect

Comment: @Macin Interesting; I tried in Base-X and it worked, but now it seems it only works with that particular `ActivityID`, but not with the other two...  Let me check further.

Answer (score 1):

> *Testing it here: videlibri.de/cgi-bin/xidelcgi*

If you're using [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel), then please add its tag. And maybe [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) for Windows, or [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) for Unix as well.

<s>I'm not too sure this can be done with XPath.</s> I believe you're better off using XQuery.

For the narrative with `<ActivityID>123456789</ActivityID>` you could do:

```
$ xidel -s input.xml --xquery '
  normalize-space(
    for $x in //ActivityNarrativeInformation
    where $x/ActivityID = 123456789
    order by $x/ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber
    return
    $x/ActivityNarrativeText
  )
'
```

For all narratives I'd suggest:

```
$ xidel -s input.xml --xquery '
  for $narrative at $i in //ActivityNarrativeInformation
  group by $id:=$narrative/ActivityID
  count $i
  return (
    $i,
    normalize-space(
      for $seq in $narrative
      order by $seq/ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber
      return
      $seq/ActivityNarrativeText
    )
  )
'
1
Once upon a time there were three bears, [...]
2
She Sells Sea Shells by the Sea Shore and [...]
3
It was a dark and stormy night; the rain [...]
```

Group by `<ActivityID>` first, then in another for-loop order the sentences by `<ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber>`.

**Update 2021-07-05**; I forgot about XPath's `!`. In that case one for-loop is enough:

```
$ xidel -s input.xml --xquery '
  for $narrative at $i in //ActivityNarrativeInformation
  order by $narrative/ActivityNarrativeSequenceNumber
  group by $id:=$narrative/ActivityID
  count $i
  return (
    $i,
    normalize-space($narrative ! ActivityNarrativeText)
  )
'
```

Comment: How does normalize-space() work on a sequence here?  normalize-space() is supposed to accept at most one string.  When passing a sequence of strings to xidel's normalize-space() it appears to only act on the first string.  Saxon and Zorba both, correctly, give a cardinality error.  Is $narrative always going to have exactly one item in this example?

Comment: @DavidDenenberg No, `$narrative` is a sequence. If `normalize-space()` with your `xidel` binary only returns the first string, then your binary is too old. `normalize-space()` accept sequences as input. That's at least how I interpret https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-normalize-space. And a recent `xidel` build supports it.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be an older binary.  I won't doubt whether recent versions of xidel support this, but it is an incorrect interpretation of the specification.  Clearly shows 
"xs:string?" as the parameter (zero or one atomic strings).

Comment: @DavidDenenberg: Xidel also gives an error in [standard XQuery mode](https://videlibri.de/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=&=&extract=normalize-space((%22a%22%2C%22b%22))%0A%0A&=&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Standard%20XQuery&dot-notation=off&extract-kind=xquery3.1&no-extended-strings=true&no-json=true&no-json-literals=true&only-json-objects=true&strict-type-checking=true&strict-namespaces=true&case-sensitive=true). But all type checking is disabled by default because then the query evaluation runs like 20% faster